# CASE statement with Bulk copy, export to csv

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, case, export-to-csv

> I am exporting files to .csv using bulk copy utility, I have eight
>   tables and want to ***avoid making eight different procedures***, How can I
>   put it all inside this one ?

Here is my attempt...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[generateCSV]') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateCSV]
GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateCSV]

(
 @table varchar(100),
 @output varchar(100), 
 @date varchar(12),
 @server varchar(30)
)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @sqlClients varchar(8000)



SELECT @sqlClients = 

   CASE @table WHEN 'Clients' THEN 'bcp "select 
* from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + @table  + ' 
where ReportingDate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  @output + '  -c 
-C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server 

  WHEN 'Receivables' THEN 'bcp "SELECT * from ' + DB_NAME() + + '.dbo.' + 
   @table  + ' where ReportingDate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  
   @output + '  -c -C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server 

  ...
END

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sqlClients 




       -- Main EXEC

EXEC dbo.generateCSV @table = 'Clients', @date = '2017-10-31', @output = 
'//172.18.16.109/share/Test.csv (server with export target location ) ', 
@server = '172.18.16.108(server we are connected to and from which we are 
taking the data)'
```

I have eight more tables,besides Clients and Receivables,and ***based on @table parameter provided in the main procedure call I want different bcp select.
How can I do this?*** 
When I run the above script I will receive:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `PRINT`-ing whatever is put into the variable `@sqlClients`, and if doing so does not make it obvious what's wrong, add that output into your question. A possible suspect is `-S' + @server`, maybe this needs a space in between?

Comment: No it does not need space, I got this working individually, for one table.
Also it seems that I can't print @sqlClients, when I do so, same error shows up but nothing gets printed in the console.

Comment: Do you have an `END` at the end of all your `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to inappropriate ending of case statement while assigning value to  @sqlClients. Just add 'End ' keyword  at the end of below statement -

SELECT @sqlClients =

```
   CASE @table WHEN 'Clients' THEN 'bcp "select 
* from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + @table  + ' 
where ReportingDate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  @output + '  -c 
-C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server 

  WHEN 'Receivables' THEN 'bcp "SELECT * from ' + DB_NAME() + + '.dbo.' + 
   @table  + ' where ReportingDate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  
@output + '  -c -C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server end --<<<----MISSING END KEYWORD
```

Comment: Silly me. Thank you so much.